# Send multicast from all network adapters to 239.255.255.253 (Port: 427) and receive messages C#

Tags: c#, networking, multicast

I recorded a sequence with Wireshark on one specific netwrok adapter.

And there I saw that outgoing multicast from one of my network adapter to 239.255.255.253. This is followed by a response from a "device" with a specific IP address.

What I already have:

```
public List<IPAddress> GetLocalNetworkInterfaces()
{
    localNetworkInterfaces = new List<IPAddress>();

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        foreach (var unicastIp in nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && unicastIp.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                && !IPAddress.IsLoopback(unicastIp.Address))
            {
                localNetworkInterfaces.Add(unicastIp.Address);

            }
        }
    }

    return localNetworkInterfaces;
}


public void SendMultiCast(List<IPAddress> iPAddresses, int port)
{
    responseOfAvailableVehicles = new List<string>();
    string availableVehicle;

    if (iPAddresses.Count != 0)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (IPAddress iPAddress in iPAddresses)
            {
                IPAddress address = iPAddress;
                byte[] response;
                long longFromIP = 4026531837; //Is 239.255.255.253
                port = 427;


                UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(address, 0));
                udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;

                // Here start Multicast
                // And receive response
                var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(longFromIP, port);
                udpClient.EnableBroadcast = true;

                udpClient.Send(DiscoveryPayload, DiscoveryPayload.Length, endpoint);
                response = udpClient.Receive(ref endpoint);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if the approach is correct at all or if I'm completely on the wrong track.

How can I also send a multicast with C# and receive the response?

Comment: Routes and Severs do not usually forward BroadCast message unless you change a setting in the device.  Multicast is a type of UDP BroadCast message.  You may need to change the device to a simple hub which does not block any traffic.

Comment: Lets assume that routes and servers forward the broadcast message. How to continue?

Comment: I have now extended the whole with `udpClient.Send`. But here exactly I get a "A socket operation referred to an unavailable network" exception.

Comment: @AlexF But I don't want to send it to the broadcast address but only to 239.255.255.253. Can I still use the broadcast address?

Comment: It is not a multicast is you send it to one specific IP.